# Need to pass a value from JavaScript to a servlet page

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

How do I pass a value from JavaScript code to a servlet page?

Comment: come on show a bit of effort, try doing some research

Comment: @david I suspect over the past ~3 months it probably got researched or solved ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks for the heads up, i didn't realize the question was so old, i think i will delete my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding , Create a hidden input field , set the value and submit to the action and get the hidden field value from servlet.

This shows a kick-off example , you can modify it according to your needs : 
  HTML Form :

```
<form name="myForm">  
<input type=hidden name="hiddenValue"/>  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="buttonSubmit" onclick="customSubmit(10)"/>  
</form>
```

Script :

```
<script>  
 function customSubmit(someValue){  
 document.form1.hiddenValue.value = someValue;   
 document.form1.submit();  
 }  
</script>
```

You would user [Request.getParameter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to get this value from servlet .

Answer (score 1):

With a field as follows:

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="variableName" VaLUE="">
```

Then in Javascript you can do:

```
document.form.variableName.value="value";
form.submit();
```

and the JSP can evaluate the param "variableName". Remember though, that a Parameter is always a String (or an array of strings if accessed through a different method) so you will need a way to transform this string to what you want, if you want something other than a String (e.g. an Integer).

Bt to tell you the truth I am not sure what you by a null value in javascript. Don't forget that anything that the JSP reads from the params, must then turn around and insert the value back into the hidden field to be read by the javascript on the client (or actually modify the javascript in the JSP before returning the html to the client).